# X2 capacitor voltage?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, ac

Just a general question. If using a X2 rated safety box capacitor on a 240V AC line, will 275V voltage rating value be appropriate?

I know that peak of the sine wave can reach 310V but can these capacitors handle them or should I choose a higher rating?

This is the type of capacitor I'm referring to. It's rated 275V

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 275VAC is a nominal rating; it means that you can use it on an AC supply that is (nominally) less than 275V RMS. The max voltage that it can actually withstand is much higher, probably over 2000VDC.  Check the data sheet.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. If 275V is nominal rating for X2 capacitors then is it the same case for Polyfilm capacitors too? I've seen them rated for 400V and some for 600V.

Comment: No, this applies to safety-rated X and Y capacitors, not to all capacitors in general.

Answer (score 2):

These are X2, hence across the line application rated capacitors. By definition they can handle power lines. In this case 275VAC. So also 240AC.

Peak voltage is indeed sqrt(2) times higher but these capacitors are even meant for much larger peak surges.

It's all in the datasheet, really. Are you sure you know what you're doing? If you need these then you're dealing with power line applications. This could be dangerous without the proper knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know it's dangerous and I do not intend to use them with mains supply which is why I asked it as a general question. :)

Answer (score 0):

The capacitor is rated for 275VAC so it will work at 240VAC.

https://www.tecategroup.com/capacitors/applications/ac-safety-capacitors.php